# Ruby on Rails iterate through index

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my view that display an images to user:

```
<div id="lightgallery" class="col-md-8 detailpage-images-gallery" >
 <% if @product.product_attachments.present? &&@product.product_attachments.count > 0 %>
  <% @product.product_attachments.each_with_index do |attachment, index| %>

    <% if index == 0 %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 topleftimg <%='hidden-xs' if index !=  @product.product_attachments.count - 1 %>" data-responsive="<%= attachment.attachment.large.url %>" data-src="<%= attachment.attachment.large.url %>" data-sub-html="<%= @product.highlight %>">
        <a class="photo-grid-photo photo-trigger" style="background-image:url('<%= attachment.attachment.square.url %>');" href="#" title="Photo 2 of 6" data-index="1" data-prevent-default="true">
        <img src="<%= attachment.attachment.square.url %>" class="hide" alt="Photo 2 of 6"></a>
      </div>

    <% elsif index == 1 %>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 toprightimg <%='hidden-xs' if index != @product.product_attachments.count - 1 %>" data-responsive="<%= attachment.attachment.large.url %>" data-src="<%= attachment.attachment.large.url %>" data-sub-html="<%= @product.highlight %>">                
      <a href=""><img src="<%= attachment.attachment.small.url %>" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <% end %>                       
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

In my view I limit the display up to 5 images, but once user click they can see more than 5 images. How can I iterate through `index` rather than using `<% if index == 0%>` to fetch all the images? And how can I modify the css so that, if more than 5 images present, I can append `style="display:none"` to the rest of `div`? Thanks!!

Comment: are you referring to pagination?  or simply how to iterate through 5 elements?

Comment: @maxpleaner simple iteration through the index.

Comment: Is using js an option? If so you can set up an on click function on your button to change the css.

Comment: @margo, cant use js here, because `lightgallery` will use the `div` inside the  index to pop up a gallery presentation with all the small thumbs

Comment: _Sidenote_: `&& @product.product_attachments.count` is completely senseless and demonstrates a poor understanding of how booleans are organized in ruby. `@product.product_attachments.count` is *never* evaluated to `falsey`. `if @product.product_attachments.present?` is completely senseless either, since `product_attachments` is a relation and can not be `nil`.

Comment: @mudasobwa appreciate for the tips!!